# Implemented custom hash class but it causes program to crash with negative integers

Tags: c++, hash

I have been trying to implement the simple hashing method which works perfectly with positive integers but it crashes with negative numbers. Here's the code:

```
void HashTable::insert(long long int key){
    //hash function: h(k) = k mod (p)
    long long int hash = key % tableSize;

        while (hashTable[hash] != NULL){
            // Change hash value to next position (+1)
            hash = (hash + 1) % tableSize;
        }

        hashTable[hash] = key;
}
```

The problem is that the result of the mod will be negative when the key is negative and it causes program to crash. It works when I take its absolute value but then I'm not sure if it's the right method.

Any Suggestions?

**Edit: here is the class:**

```
class HashTable{

private:
    long int tableSize;
    long long int *hashTable;

public:

    HashTable(long int);
    void insert(long long int);
};
```

Comment: Show declaration of your used variables.

Comment: `boost::unordered_map`.

Comment: @Blacktempel added the class to OP

Comment: The point of hashing is to use a reproducible scrambler.  abs() fits that description.

Answer (score 0):

Just take your key as `unsigned` - no need to perform an extra operation just to get a positive number:

```
void HashTable::insert(uint64_t key){
    //hash function: h(k) = k mod (p)
    uint64_t hash = key % tableSize;

    // rest as before
}
```

Alternatively, if you make your `tableSize` member `unsigned`, then the result of the `%` operator will also be `unsigned`.

Comment: So even if I use abs(key) to make it positive, it is the right method of dealing with negative numbers?

Comment: @Kronos Nothing at all logically wrong with `abs()`. Just proposing alternative solutions which may be faster.